# Why is the scheme associated to a product of quasi-projective varieties naturally isomorphic to the product of the associated schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

What I mean by this is, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are quasi-projective varieties over some arbitrary field $k$. Then $X\times Y$ is again a quasi-projective variety. I've seen this a few times, but what is the rigorous explanation for why we can make the identification $$\widetilde{X\times Y}\simeq\tilde{X}\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(k)}\tilde{Y}$$ between the associated schemes of $X\times Y$, $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: This is Chapter II, Exercise 3.23 in Hartshorne. It boils down to the fact that the functor $t \colon \mathsf{Var}/k \to \mathsf{Sch}/k$ defined in Proposition 2.6 is fully faithful, and the fibre product over $\operatorname{Spec} k$ in $\mathsf{Sch}/k$ and the product in $\mathsf{Var}/k$ satisfy the same universal property by comparing Chapter I, Exercise 3.16(*c*) and Chapter II, Theorem 3.3.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama It's possible to be more specific? Sorry for being so stupid...  I want to prove that the object $\widetilde{X \times Y}$ satisfy the same universal property of the tensor product $\widetilde{X} \times_{Spec(k)} \widetilde{Y}$
I know that this is stupid but, what are the projection maps $\pi_X: \widetilde{X \times Y} \to X$ and the analogous $\pi_Y$ defined on the universal property of the tensor product?

Comment: @Ergos the projection maps are the maps you obtain from applying the Varieties to Scheme function to the projections on the variety side

Comment: @TakumiMurayama I did not understand what you said Dx I'm reading Hartshorne and I'm having some troubles with this section, the main reason is because all the proofs that I read are incomplete, for example everyone says that glueing the result is proved but I think that sometimes it is not trivial to glue. That's why I want to prove some results with detailed solutions, to develop some intuition in this theory.